# Counting Occurrences in char array

Tags: c#

Write a function that accepts a character array as input, counts the number of occurrences for each character in the array, and outputs the result in format(eg {'c', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'a', 'q'} would be

```
a - *
c - *
e - ***
q - *
```

I tried again with the dictionary but how do I get the asterisk

```
    class Program
    {
    public static void Main()
    {
        char[] characters = { 'c', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'a', 'q' };
        charFuction(characters);
    }

    static Dictionary<char, int> occurrences = new Dictionary<char, int>();
    static void charFuction(char[] characters)
    {
        foreach(char c in characters)
        {
            if (occurrences.ContainsKey(c))
            {
                occurrences[c]++;
            }
            else
            {
                occurrences.Add(c, 1);
            }
        }
        foreach(char k in occurrences.Keys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(k + " - " + occurrences[k]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please edit to show what you have tried.

Comment: Here's a hint: use a `Dictionary<char, int>` for keeping track of the count of each `char` seen.

Answer (score 1):

With LINQ:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetCharCountPlaceholders(IEnumerable<char> chars, char placeholder = '*', string charCountDelimiter = " - ")
{
    return chars
        .GroupBy(c => c)
        .OrderBy(g => g.Key)
        .Select(g => String.Format("{0}{1}{2}"
         , g.Key
         , charCountDelimiter
         , new String(placeholder, g.Count())));
}
```

You could call it for example in this way:

```
char[] chars = { 'c', 'e', 'e', 'e', 'a', 'q' };
string result = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, GetCharCountPlaceholders(chars));

a - *
c - *
e - ***
q - *
```

Comment: Actually more like `g => $"{g.Key} - {new string('*', g.Count()}"`

Comment: @juharr: true, thought that OP was just too lazy to insert the actual count for each char since he hasn't mentioned the placeholder requirement.

Comment: I'm not sure they were being lazy.  I'm guessing the assignment was intending the output to look like a bar chart.

Comment: I appreciate you all. Sorry for my limited knowledge I'm new to this but I'm more than determined.